# Strange npm error in console

Tags: npm

I am using Linux Mint 18.3.I am getting following error when I run `npm run serve` in vue.js.

[image]

I am not getting error when I run `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` and `sudo sysctl -p --system`.

Why I am getting error ? What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It says you don’t have enough space, so clean up some space on the device.

Comment: Thanks @Elhoej. Where should I clean ? How much space does it need ?

Comment: It shouldn’t matter where you delete some files, try and clear up 20mb.

Comment: Thanks @Elhoej. Where should I clean ?